# Disable thrift in Cassandra 3.x

Tags: java, cassandra, janusgraph

Is it possible to disable thrift in Cassandra 3.x?

Looked into `nodetool disablethrift` and also `start_rpc` setting of Cassandra.yaml, however is it possible to stop shipping `libthrift` jar from Cassandra library?

Not able to start Cassandra if the jar is removed as there is exception with NoClassDefFoundError.

> ERROR [main] CassandraDaemon.java:749 - Exception encountered during startup
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransportFactory
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:435) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportFactory
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
>           ... 3 common frames omitted

Not sure but just wanted to check if there is any workaround for same?

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra 3 Thrift is disabled by default, so your best bet is to leave it just like this:

```
# Whether to start the thrift rpc server.
start_rpc: false
```

The `libthrift` JAR has been removed in Cassandra 4.0, so you shouldn't have to worry about this in the future.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I think in Cassandra 3 removing `libthrift` jar would not be possible then and will have to continue with this jar. Cassandra 4.0 is not yet available for download, any insight when it will be released.